# Any java library implementing Queue on top of array with automatic resizing?

Tags: java, arrays, queue

Standard Java does not offer an object implementing the [Queue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) interface on top of an array with automatic resizing of this underlying array when too many objects are added (I don't want linked lists).

Is there any open source library offering this implementation or should I implement it myself?

**Update**

There is a class available in Java 6 (ArrayDeque), for some reason, I was reading Java 5 documentation.

Comment: Huh? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html

Comment: I would think it wouldn't be too hard to implement an array-backed queue yourself.  Just wrap an ArrayList in a queue interface implementation and handle the logic for each method yourself.

Comment: @sjr It says "Resizable-array implementation of the Deque interface." I'm confused. ;)

Comment: The issue though is the memory allocation with arrays, you would have to be very careful of your initial size  (well along with copying over the previous elements to a new array with a larger size).

Comment: It implements Deque and Queue.

Comment: Don't listen to people to say "implement it yourself". Go with ArrayDeque.

Comment: @sjr I missed that. Thanks. If you create an answer, I'll approve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [ArrayDeque](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayDeque.html). It implements Queue on top of a resizing array.